# Why can't I save user's input? Trying to pass 3 doubles and updating their sizes

Tags: c

I am writing in C. I am trying to make a function that passes 3 doubles for a triangle. I am trying to save the user's input into these 3 variables but it crashes after entering the first number. If I remove the pointers, it would work fine but I need to pass these values from another file.

````
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL) {
        }
        
        value = strtod(input, &endptr);
        if (((*endptr == '\0') || (isspace(*endptr) != 0)) && (value > 0)) {
            // save values
            if (side1 == 0) {
                *side1 = value;
            }
            else if (side2 == 0) {
                ...
            }
            else if ...
            }
    }
    else {  
        ...
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What is `side1`, etc? Code is incomplete, specifically missing the variable definitions which are vital to the question. Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: `(*endptr == '\0')` should only match if reading from a redirected file with a non-POSIX ending, or if `Ctrl+d` is used to terminate input. Your problem seems to come from elsewhere in your code. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `if (side1 == 0) {
                *side1 = value;` please explain the asterisk in one place before side1 and the absence of ab asterisk in the other place before side1 to your nearest rubber duck.

Comment: `fgets` stores the newline character `'\n'` in the end of the input string, so you better check for that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the use of `(*endptr == '\0')` is correct here. `fgets` will properly zero-terminate the stored string.

Comment: @HAL9000 - read the comment carefully. I didn't say it was wrong, simply that it will only match on two conditions (1) last line in a file with non-POSIX line ending, and (2) if the user terminates input with `Ctrl+d` (or `Ctrl+z` on windows)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, .. or a third condition: the input line is longer than 1023 chars. (including the `\n`). But, yes your original comment was not wrong, I just thought it needed clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to save the user's input into these 3 variables

Code is not doing that.

Instead it is incorrectly trying to save when the pointer is invalid.

Instead, save when the pointer is *not* 0.

```
// if (side1 == 0) {
if (side1) {
    *side1 = value;
}
 // same for side2, side 3
```

---

Yet I think OP wants to save, not based on `side1`, etc. but based on `i`.

```
void foo(double *side1, double *side2, double *side3) {
  ...  
        if (i == 0) {
            *side1 = value;
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            *side2 = value;
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            *side3 = value;
        }
  ...
}
```

---

> I am trying to make a function that passes 3 doubles for a triangle

Wrong approach.

Make a function that passes 3 double *pointers* for a triangle.

Usage example:

```
double side1, side2, side3;
foo(&side1, &side2, &side3);
printf("%g %g %g\n", side1, side2, side3);
```